# "Invalid content-type specified" when uploading file to Apigility

Tags: php, file-upload, laminas-api-tools

I'm a building a RPC API using Zend Framework 2 and Apigility by Zend Framework. For testing, I use the chrome extension Postman REST-Client.

I can do POST requests without problems when I use Postman.
But my code doesn't work.

```
$client = new \Zend\Http\Client();
$client->setUri($uri)
        ->setMethod('POST')
        ->setParameterPost(
            array(
                'file' => '/home/user/Downloads/file.csv'
            )
        );

$headers = new \Zend\Http\Headers();

$headers->addHeaders(array(
    'Accept' => 'application/json;',
));

$client->setHeaders($headers);

$client->setStream();
$response = $client->send();

$file = '/home/user/Downloads/file.csv';
$file2 = '/home/user/Downloads/file2.csv';
copy($response->getStreamName(), $file);
$fp = fopen($file2, "w");
stream_copy_to_stream($response->getStream(), $fp);
$client->setStream($file);

$responce = $client->send();

echo $responce->getBody();
```

I tried to pass other headers `Content-Type`, but it leads to Fatal error.
What do I need to pass the headers to make it work?

Comment: What is the fatal error?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do a file upload. Have you read this? https://apigility.org/documentation/recipes/upload-files-to-api

Comment: You have a typo in your variable `$response` (`$responce`) and you should not add a `;` at the end of your `Accept` header value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your `Content-Type` header to `multipart/form-data`. The Postman add-on you are using in Chrome does this automatically for file uploads.

So set your headers like this:

```
$headers->addHeaders(array(
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'
));
```

*If that doesn't work please be more specific about the fatal error you get.*